# CTE-common table exp in t-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a problem with the following query:

```
WITH CTE_1 (stu_id
            ,meet_doc_id
            ,doc_name
            ,stu_name
            ,dob
            ,done
            ,date_meet_doc)
AS

(SELECT stu_id
        ,meet_doc_id
        ,doc_name
        ,stu_name
        ,dob
        ,CASE
              WHEN (PATINDEX('%SMOKING%',act.VALUE)) THEN 
                           'LMDO'                       
              WHEN (PATINDEX('%NOT SMOKING%',act.VALUE)) THEN  
                            'LMD1'                       
              WHEN (ISNULL(CAST(act.VALUE as varchar(max)),'')='') THEN     
                            'CLEAR'                       
              ELSE                                   
                            'CLEAR'    
              END done 
        ,date_meet_doc

FROM 
abc INNER JOIN
INNER JOIN 
INNER JOIN 
WHERE multiple conditions
)

SELECT * FROM CTE_1 one
WHERE date =(SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM CTE_1 two WHERE two.stu_id=one.stu_id
AND one.doc_name=two.doc_name)
ORDER BY stu_name,dob
;
```

The result set of the inner query(CTE_1) for three student(for eg) will be something like

```
stu_id   meet_doc_id   doc_name   stu_name      dob        value      date
101        0104          AD          AM      15/06/1950     LMDO     2011-02-15
101        0105          AD          AM      15/06/1950     CLEAR    2011-02-18
101        0106          AD          AM      15/06/1950     CLEAR    2011-02-25
102        0107          AD          AK      12/08/1987     CLEAR    2011-03-28
102        0108          AD          AK      12/08/1987     LDMO     2011-04-29
103        0109          PK          LMP     13/07/1970     CLEAR    2011-03-28
103        0110          PK          LMP     13/07/1970     CLEAR    2011-05-12
```

AND when i execute the whole query my result set will be

```
stu_id   meet_doc_id   doc_name   stu_name      dob         value      date
101        0106          AD          AM      15/06/1950     CLEAR    2011-02-25
102        0108          AD          AK      12/19/1987     LDMO     2011-04-29
103        0110          PK          LMP     13/07/1970     CLEAR    2011-05-12
```

**What do i have to do to change the outer query to select only those value ie LDMO or LMD1 for a particular student and whose doctor is same?**

Suppose if the student meets the doc multiple times and if in any of the cases if the student gets a LMDO or LMD1 then it should pick only that record irrespective of the date.

I am expecting my resultset to be something like:

```
stu_id   meet_doc_id   doc_name   stu_name      dob         value      date
101        0104          AD          AM      15/06/1950     LMDO     2011-02-15
102        0107          AD          AK      12/08/1987     CLEAR    2011-03-28
103        0110          PK          LMP     13/07/1970     CLEAR    2011-05-12
```

The logic behind it is if the stu_id is same and the doc_name is same and if there exists a value either LMDO or LMD1 then show that record if not show the record which has CLEAR.
    Simply i want to remove the MAX(date) and place a condition for the whole reporting period of that particular stu_id with the same doc_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @TestTable
as table
(stu_id int,
 meet_doc_id  char(4), 
 doc_name  char(2), 
 stu_name  varchar(3),   
 dob date,
 value  varchar(5),
 date_meet_doc date)

insert into @TestTable
(stu_id,meet_doc_id,doc_name,stu_name,dob,value,date_meet_doc)
values
(101,'0104','AD','AM', '19500615','LDMO' ,'2011-02-15'),
(101,'0105','AD','AM', '19500615','CLEAR','2011-02-18'),
(101,'0106','AD','AM', '19500615','CLEAR','2011-02-25'),
(102,'0107','AD','AK', '19870812','CLEAR','2011-03-28'),
(102,'0108','AD','AK', '19870812','LDMO' ,'2011-04-29'),
(103,'0109','PK','LMP','19700713','CLEAR','2011-03-28'),
(103,'0110','PK','LMP','19700713','CLEAR','2011-05-12');

WITH CTE_1 (stu_id
                ,meet_doc_id
                ,doc_name
                ,stu_name
                ,dob
                ,done
                ,date_meet_doc)
    AS

    (SELECT stu_id
            ,meet_doc_id
            ,doc_name
            ,stu_name
            ,dob
            ,value
            ,date_meet_doc

    FROM @TestTable
    ),
    CTE_2 as(
    SELECT *,row_number() over (partition by stu_id order by  case when done in ('LDMO','LDM1') then 0 else 1 end, date_meet_doc desc) rn FROM CTE_1) 
    select stu_id
            ,meet_doc_id
            ,doc_name
            ,stu_name
            ,dob
            ,value
            ,date_meet_doc
    from CTE_2 where rn=1
    ;
```

**Thanks to those who tried to understand but gave up since i couldnt explain it. 
Thanks Again guys :)**

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: To add a high-level description of what I did.

You want to get your original information (CTE_1) filtered down by 2 possible criteria. The easiest way to do this is to first establish those criteria in their own result sets. So, we have a subquery that returns a list of `(Student, Doc, Max(Date))` combinations and a similar list that is filtered on the `LMDO/LMD1` values.

Now, we need to `LEFT JOIN` to the filtered data since there may not be results for each student.

So now you have a list of `Student/Doc/MaxDate` and also a possible `FilteredDate`.

The final step is to `JOIN` that result set to the original data (CTE_1). Since the FilteredDate takes precedence, we check for that first through the `ISNULL` function and, if it isn't present, we use the MaxDate instead.

---

First, I'd change the original query to the following as I think you'll see some performance gains on large data-sets by eliminating the correlated subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CTE_1 one
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT stu_id, doc_name, max(date) maxdate FROM CTE_1 group by stu_id,doc_name) two
  ON one.stu_id = two.stu_id and one.doc_name = two.doc_name
ORDER BY stu_name,dob
```

Now, we can add an additional, similar, join to get the max(date) where the Value is in your desired list. We'll need to shuffle the joins around a little bit too.

```
SELECT realdata.* 
FROM 
  ((SELECT stu_id, doc_name, max(date) maxdate FROM CTE_1 group by stu_id,doc_name) maxdt
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT stu_id, doc_name, max(date) maxdate FROM CTE_1 
   WHERE value in ('LMDO', 'LMD1')
   group by stu_id,doc_name) filtered
  ON maxdt.stu_id = filtered.stu_id and maxdt.doc_name = filtered.doc_name)
INNER JOIN CTE_1 realdata
  ON realdata.stu_id = maxdt.stu_id and realdata.doc_name = maxdt.doc_name
     and realdata.date = isnull(filtered.maxdate, maxdt.maxdate)
ORDER BY realdata.stu_name,realdata.dob
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Derek atlest u didnt give up,for trying to undertand my senario. Below is the answer which worked out for me. Thanks Again :)